# ng-template added to $templateCache as empty string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following html

```
<div ng-app="theapp" id="ng-app">

    <!-- templates -->
    <script type="text/ng-template" src="https://app.com/templates/about.html" id="templates/about.html"></script>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</div>
```

I'd expect `'templates/about.html'` to be in the `$templateCache`...and it is ...(not `undefined`)...but the value is an empty string. I'm checking this in the Chrome debugger in my angular module controller.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)**. You can't point to external URL template file with script `type="text/ng-template"`. When Angular sees such script tags with custom template type, it will use their inner text content to put into template cache. Angular will not download anything.

For reference I can put here compile function of the [`scriptDirective`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/c94329a891a1c082567c490ccf58ba8592b464ad/src/ng/directive/script.js#L36):

```
compile: function(element, attr) {
  if (attr.type == 'text/ng-template') {
    var templateUrl = attr.id,
        // IE is not consistent, in scripts we have to read .text but in other nodes we have to read .textContent
        text = element[0].text;

    $templateCache.put(templateUrl, text);
  }
}
```

As you can see, it's no surprise that you end up with empty string template in your case: your `src` attributes is never used, and script text is indeed empty.

**2)**. While I don't think this is a very good idea but it's possible to create one more `script` directive (because you can have many directives with the same name) which would be respect `src` and download template for you:

```
.directive('script', ['$templateCache', '$http',
    function($templateCache, $http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            terminal: true,
            compile: function(element, attr) {
                if (attr.type == 'text/ng-template' && attr.src && !attr.id) {
                    $http.get(attr.src, { cache: $templateCache });
                }
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/TChPjDr9iAq4Zi55N0rq?p=preview

Comment: How can I accomplish having templates loaded and cached from an external location?

Comment: Well you can create your own `script` directive with this capability. See updated answer.